# ¿Cómo lograr efecto en layout en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

¿Cómo puedo lograr el efecto que se muestar en la foto en un layout en Android Studio?[image: layout con efecto]

Comment: Puedes agregar el código del layout

Comment: Felix, es importante revises [ask] y cuando una pregunta se de ayuda a resolver un problema, agradece marcando como correcta, ya que veo todas tus preguntas no tienen respuesta aceptada, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas se puede realizar con un `CardView`, te dejo un ejemplo de como lo realizaría yo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#efefef"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Esto es un texto de prueba"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#52aef7"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

el resultado sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesitas la librería **Design** de *Google* para usar `CardView`:

> compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

Cambia a tu gusto `app:cardElevation="5dp"` según la sombra que le quieras dar.

Comment: Excelente, definitivamente usar un CardView!, saludos

Comment: me funciono perfecto, solo tube que añadir la libreria compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'